# CentOS 5 VPS - setting the date and time

Tags: vps, time, timezone

I've just tried to set the timezone on my VPS to Europe/London:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
```

This was fine. However, the time is now wildly out:

```
$ date
Sat Feb  5 12:33:21 GMT 2011
```

When it is in fact 22:31.

With it being a VPS, trying to do

```
$ date -s 22:31
```

also fails.

Is this something I can fix, or do I need my host to do something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if using xen, try

echo 1 > /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock

and set date time again

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this from the `date` man page?

```
   date [-u|--utc|--universal] [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
```

So, for 22:31, you'd type `date 02052231`.

or the full string containing century, year and seconds...

`date 020522312011.00`

Comment: # date 02052237
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted. I think it's due to the server being a VPS.

Comment: Do you have access to an `ntpdate` command? Perhaps `ntpdate time.apple.com`

Comment: No ntpdate, but I suspect the result would be the same as using date. rdate certainly doesn't work (same error as above).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
/bin/rm /etc/localtime
/bin/ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
```

See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-change-setup-timezone-tz-variable/) for more info. Only works on RH systems I believe.

Comment: I did this to set the timezone, and it's done that fine (at least, the time is reported as being GMT) -- but the time itself is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, how odd. Should change the time in all applications.